# I can´t run WHISPER openai on GPU in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, openai-api, openai-whisper

I am having this result for model.device = cpu whith this code. How can i switch to my gpu (laptop msi + nvidia rtx2060)

import whisper
from IPython.display import Audio

```
model = whisper.load_model("base")
Audio("audioingles.mp3")

print (model.device)
```